# Why are my emails going to spam folder?

Tags: email, sendmail, spam, blacklist

My server ip is `78.46.138.249` and none of the blacklists I could find blacklist my domain. Nevertheless, many of my customers recieve their emails in their SPAM folder. I just created a live.com account and my registration confirmation email went to SPAM.

My email is just a regular Magento confirm your account email.

Any ideas why this happening?

you can see my mail source here:
http://dadilja.rs/mail.txt

Comment: Do you have an [SPF (Sender Policy Framework)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) record for your domain(s)?

Comment: seems like I don't. Will add. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that you have to do which are often being checked by receivers:

- SPF records http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework
- DKIM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM
- DNS reverse lookup from your sending IP has to match forward lookup and FQDN
- Make sure your configured FQDN matches the DNS
- Reputation (If many users who receive your mails are marking it as spam, receivers will remember that)
- Dynamic IPs are generally also very bad for your reputation

Answer (score 2):

As an offhand guess, the fact that your MX server is misconfigured, CentOS-63-64-minimal.localdomain is not a proper FQDN, and for sure has no RDNS entry or proper MX record?

Comment: my domain has a zohomail MX record, whereas server uses sendmail to send mail - could that be a problem? - RDNS points to your-domain.de , which is stack where my server is hosted, but is not my domain

Comment: Those are problems, the mail should show the mail coming from your FQDN, the one configured as your MX server, and if possible, the RDNS should match. That alone is enough to ensure your email will finish in many spam folders.